# The best way to send a file over a Network

Tags: java, php, rest, download, network-protocols

I want to send a file to the Browser via the `REST` Interface.

Can you suggest the most efficient way to do it, Keeping in mind the following?

1. Not much traffic.
2. I am fetching the file from `HBase` which means when I fetch it from HBase I get it in `Byte Array`.
3. The files are not in any folder in the server. The files can only be fetched from the `HBase` table.

The Front end is `PHP` and I do not know `PHP`.

Comment: Just write the byte data to the http response's output stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `REST` api you can just pass the `byte array` to `Response` and it takes care of itself.

Using the following code -

```
@Produces("image/jpg")
public Response getImage() {
    <Fetch it from where ever you have it>
    Response.ok(<byteArrayOfTheFile>).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am giving  case study of WebService by which i send file:**

It is always good to encode the file content and send it to the destination where they will be decode it and read the content.

Sending as an attachment is always open to the world becasue it is not encrypted.And if the network having high trafic chances of failure is high.

Comment: @Abisek did you not mean encrypt and decrypt the file? Encoding is not secure.

Comment: Encrypt and Decrypt is more secure due to the involvment of certificate exchange.

Comment: Agreed if you are using Asymmetrical encryption if you are using symmetrical encryption there is no certificate exchange. However in your answer you say he should encode and decode the files. Encoding is NOT secure. I assume you are speaking about Base64 encoding. Could you clarify this in your answer.

Comment: Ya encoding is never secure.It all depends if you are under using VPN or Intranet connectivity then Encode a file is good other wise if the application is open to the world then send the file content in encrypted way.